# undefined method `page_path' rails

Tags: routes, namespaces, ruby-on-rails-5.1

Rails 5.1.3

I have a namespaced set of routes in my route file within rails:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'page/index'

  namespace :admin do
    resources :pages
    resources :sections
  end

  get '*page', to: 'page#index'

  root 'page#index'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

I then have a pages controller:

```
class Admin::PagesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    render layout: 'admin'
  end

  def index
    @pages = Page.all

    render layout: 'admin'    
  end

  def edit    
    @page = Page.find(params[:id])

    render layout: 'admin'    
  end
end
```

As you can see I have defined my edit method in which I get the page for the corresponding ID (fairly typical).

Within my HTML I then have:

```
<h1>Edit page</h1>

<%= form_with(model: @page) do |form| %>

 <p>
   <%= form.label :slug %><br>
   <%= form.text_field :slug %>
 </p>

 <p>
   <%= form.label :title %><br>
   <%= form.text_area :title %>
 </p>

 <p>
   <%= form.submit %>
 </p>

<% end %>
```

As per the rails guide, but I get the error:

> undefined method `page_path' for #<#>
>   :0x007fbdfd15f000>
>   Did you mean?  image_path
>   Extracted source (around line #3):
>
> ## Edit page
>
> <%= form_with(model: @page) do |form| %>
>
> <%= form.label :slug %>

I suspect it is due to the namespace, how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, it's about the namespace:

```
<%= form_with(model: [ :admin, @page ]) do |form| %>
```

Comment: i've a question: How do i use it with an associated model? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49366165/rails-how-to-use-associated-model-with-the-admin-namespace

Comment: You can keep adding to the array: `[:admin, @parent, @page]`.

Comment: Thanks This doesn't run. But this [:admin,@a,B.new] runs for me

Comment: If you share the form between new and edit, you want it to be an instance variable that evaluates to B.new in new and B.find(params[:id]) in edit.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see where you've defined the route for 'page_path' in your routes.

You've defined 'admin_page_path'.

Use 'rails routes' to see exactly how your routes are mapped out.

Also, in your controller, you can use 'layout "admin"' after your class definition to use that layout for all actions.

Answer (score 0):

You've not named your route. Try:

```
get 'page/index', as: 'page'
```

If you run rake routes from your terminal, it gives you an extremely helpful breakdown of all your routes names, params and namespaces