# rails NoMethodError in Admin::BsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, web-development-server

after the community an i solved my problem [rails how to use Associated Model with the admin namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49366165/rails-how-to-use-associated-model-with-the-admin-namespace) i get the data from the form into the controller, my `def create` crashed.

I'm using rails 5.1.5 with ruby 2.5.0. I have two models the model A and Model B.

```
Model A has_many bs
Model B belongs_to a
```

The Controller with the crash is

**app/controllers/admin/bs_controller.rb**

```
class Admin::BsController < ApplicationController

def create
  @a = A.find(params[:a_id])
  @b = @a.bs.create(entry_params)
  redirect_to a_path(@a)
end
```

**NoMethodError in Admin::BsController#create**

**undefined method `bs' for nil:NilClass**

```
def create
  @a = A.find(params[:a_id])
  **@b = @a.bs.create(entry_params)**
  redirect_to a_path(@a)
end
```

Is it correct? First i have to find the "A-Entry" from is main Model, the i can create the new entry which belongs_to a?

Comment: Just make sure the result of `A.find(params[:wishlist_id])` isn't nil. Use a debugger, check your strong params, look for any error.

Comment: Thats right! It isn't nil. But i changed the id-handling via to_param in my model and now i need an other id because i'm using an other id.

Comment: It can't be `nil`, because `#find` raises an exception if it doesn't find the record, suggesting the code posted is not the one running when the error happens.

Comment: now i change the to_param method that the id i use. But there is an error that i've never seen before `undefined method `string' for #<E:0x00007f5699128468> Did you mean? String`